# Why does my column appear below my row rather than to the right?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I have a webpage with two columns.

The first column has 3 cards in it which I am going to use as contact cards.

The second column contains some text. But for some reason, the second column always appears directly below the first column.

How can I make the the second column appear on the right side of the first column?

**Code:**

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class = "row-sm-1">
    <div class ="col-sm-1">
      <!-- Card 1 -->
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Person</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Description</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">Email: </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Phone: </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      
      <!-- Card 2 -->
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <-- same as above -->
      </div>
      <br><br>

      <!-- Card 3 -->
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <-- same as above -->
      </div>
      <br><br>

    </div>

    <!-- Second Column -->
    <div class = "col-sm-2">

      <h1>Test</h1>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
  

<br><br><br>

{% endblock %}
```

**Result:**

[image: page]

My desired outcome is to have the test text appear to the right of the cards. The html is currently formatted like this:
Where base.html contains just basic tags like head, body, etc.

This problem seems to persist no matter how I format the columns using different classes such as `col-lg` or `col-sm`.

Comment: I want the cards to display vertically, and want the text to the right only, so I thought it would be alright to leave the cards in 1 column

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question earlier (I've now edited it to make it more clear). Anyway, bootstrap doesn't have `row-sm-1` class. Maybe replace that with just `row` and see if that works.

Comment: Seems to work thanks, guess I was overcomplicating it trying to use different row classes and such

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox classes in bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: I haven't looked into it before but it seems useful. I'll have a go, thank you